# Join DataTable with List<SomeObject>

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I have a DataTable and a List of objects. I need to return all rows in the DataTable where a property in the List is a certain value. The List is only used for filtering the datatable (but the filter column isn't containined in the datatable).

I'm sure this must be possible with LINQ.

The DataTable contains:

```
MembershipID  Username   Password   
1              blah        blah      
2              blah        blah      
3              blah        blah
```

My List contains:

```
MembershipID  Profile1   Profile2   Profile3 DifferentID   
1              blah        blah      blah    A             
2              blah        blah      blah    B             
3              blah        blah      blah    C
```

I need to return (as a DataTable) - eg: for GetUsersByDifferentID("B"):

```
MembershipID  Username   Password   
2              blah        blah      
...
```

I could get the second table as a DataTable if that would make it easier, but I think what I need is possible with LINQ. I just can't get my head around the magic syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a join:

```
List<ListItem> listItems = //whatever
DataTable dtItems = //whatever

IEnumerable<DataRow> matchingRows = listItems
    .Join(  dtItems.AsEnumerable(),
            listItem => listItem.MembershipID,
            row => row.Field<int>("MembershipID"),
            (r,li) => new { DifferentId = li.DifferentId, Row = r })
    .Where( ji => ji.DifferentID == "B")
    .Select( ji => ji.Row);
```

Change the where clause to use the actual value you want to match...

Comment: @Lee when i tried to return `ListCollection`,it throws a exception.`{System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[System.Data.DataRow]
 AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this. Let's say your List is a collection of this class:

```
public class SomeMemberClass
{
    public int MembershipId { get; set; }
    public char DifferentId { get; set; }
    //..some more properties
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("MembershipId", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("UserName");
table.Columns.Add("Password");

List<SomeMemberClass> list = new List<SomeMemberClass>(); //or get the list from somewhere else...
var differntIds = list.Select( s => s.DifferentId).Distinct();

var result = table.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where( dt => differntIds
                      .Contains((int)dt["MembershipId"]))
                      .CopyToDataTable();
```

Basically, first get all the distinct DifferentId's and then use that to look through your table.

Comment: I think you're close. I don't think you need to worry about distinct list entries as it sounds like the OP is using the list as a lookup reference. The way I understood it is: pass in the DifferentID, look through the list and get the MembershipID, then use that to return the matching row from the DataTable (and then return that as its own DataTable).

Comment: I'm just doing distinct, so that when you call Contains on the list, it has to look through less elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this because i couldnt understand that much about datatable which you mention about but can you try this

```
var usersByDifferentId = yourList.Where(a=> a["DifferentID"] == "B").Select(a=> new {a["UserName"],a["MemberShipID"],a["Password"]});
```

Comment: I need that but the other way around, to return matching rows from the datatable based on the DifferentID in the List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
var memberIds = myList.Where(u => u.DifferentID == "B").Select(a => a.MembershipID);
var credentials = myDataTable.Where(d => memberIds.Contains(d.MembershipID));
```

There may be a more efficient way to do it, but something like that should work.