# C# - Check if string is in DataRow

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Basically I have a DataTable A (see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/38RKc.png) which contains dates with their corresponding days.

I also have another DataTable B which contains the list of days a retailer can delivery on (see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTmD4.png)

What I want to do is loop through each row in DataTable A and if the day is in DataTable B then display it to the screen.

So far I have this but now I am stuck.

```
    // Firstly call the stored procedure to obtain the list available delivery dates (this is basically today plus 14 days)
DataTable availableDatesRecord = new DataTable();
B2B.Data.CometB2BDB comet = new CometB2BDB();
StoredProcedure proc = comet.GetListOfAvailableDates(now);
DbDataReader reader = proc.ExecuteReader();
availableDatesRecord.Load(reader);

// Now we need to obtain the list of days we can deliver - this is all based on their postcode.
DataTable possibleDeliveryDayRecord = new DataTable();
proc = comet.GetDeliveryDatesByPostcode(postcode);
reader = proc.ExecuteReader();
possibleDeliveryDayRecord.Load(reader);

DataRow deliveryDays = possibleDeliveryDayRecord.Rows[1];


foreach (DataRow row in availableDatesRecord.Rows)
{
string deliveryDay = row["Day"].ToString();
}
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Steven

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you post your existing code?

Comment: what is the type of your ListOfDays? Strings, an enum type,...?

Answer (score 1):

joining list and a datatable is may be what you want. Can you use Linq? if so this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412008/join-datatable-with-listsomeobject)

if you are still in 2.0, then i would just do nested loop on datarows, something like

```
List<string> days;
    foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
      if days.Contains(dr[columnname])
        Console.WriteLine(dr[columnname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple method provides some basic functionality:

String[] days = {"monday","tuesday","sunday"};

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Add("day",typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(days[0]);
table.Rows.Add(days[2]);

//query
foreach(string day in days) {
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) {
        if(row[dc] == day) {
            Console.WriteLine("Row {0} contains {1}",row,day);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```